# Reading information from a textfile to get specific information

Tags: java, text-files

I am working on an assignment where I have to create an interval(which I have already completed) and from a text file, read in the girls names that are found within the interval and put them into an array list. I also have to read in all the male names that start with the letter "J", and then calculate how many male births start with the letter "J" and print out that information. Below is the code I have so far:

```
public static int generateRandomInt(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    int value = lowerLimit + (int)Math.ceil( Math.random() * ((upperLimit - lowerLimit) + 1)); //generates a random number between 1 and 10
    return value;
}// end generateRandomInt

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Read from filename: top20namesNM1994.txt
    // Generating a interval, the lower random number comes from 50 to 100, and the upper random number comes from 150 to 200.
    // Print out this interval
    // Read all the girls names, which birth numbers are inside of the interval you construct, into a array or ArrayList.

    // Print out the array.

    //Print out all the males names, which start with letter "J".
    //Determine how many male births start with names starting with the letter "J", and print out the summary information.


    final int LOW1 = 50;
    final int LOW2 = 100;
    final int HIGH1 = 150;
    final int HIGH2 = 200;

    ArrayList<String>girlNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = "";
    int interval_low = generateRandomInt(LOW1, LOW2);
    int interval_high = generateRandomInt(HIGH1, HIGH2);
    System.out.println("The interval is ( " + interval_low + " , " + interval_high + " )" );
    try {
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\drago\\eclipse-workspace-Ch6to7FinalExam2\\MorrisJFinalExam2\\src\\top20namesNM1994.txt");
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner (inputFile);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line.split("\\s+");
            if()
            girlNames.add();

        }
    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not Found!");
    }
    if()
    System.out.println(girlNames.toString());
}
```

I am stuck on how to get the girl names that are within the interval created and also how to read in the boy names. Attached is the text file.
 [TextFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SztP.png)

Comment: This is a great time to read the docs about Files

Comment: What specifically are you stumped by? My best advice is to break down the problem into small bite size pieces and tackle them individually. The javadocs for `BufferedReader` and `split()` will get you most of the way there, and then the tutorials from Oracle should get you the rest of the way.

Comment: I am stumped because I don't know how to get the specific information from within the text file into the arrayList. I am trying to read in only the names that fit in the interval, meaning the number of births that were given the name.

Comment: I need to find a way to make the array list compare the number of girls with a certain name to the interval to form an array list with those names in it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...you know how to read in the text file (somewhat) which is good however you can simplify the code a bit:

```
ArrayList<String> girlNames = new ArrayList<>();
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\drago\\eclipse-workspace-Ch6to7FinalExam2\\"
                + "MorrisJFinalExam2\\src\\top20namesNM1994.txt"; 
String line = "";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // ..................... 
            // ..... Your Code .....
            // .....................    
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[Try With Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is used here so that your ***BufferedReader*** is automatically closed. If all your going to do is read the desired text file then the [Scanner](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class) object you have commented out in your code is also a pretty good alternative for reading text files if properly used.

It's obvious from your incomplete code that each data line within this file is *White-Space* or *Tab* delimited simply based on the [Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (`"\\s+"`) used within the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_split.htm) method (the `"\\s+"` expression will split a string on any number of white-spaces and or tabs that are contained within that string). **Do Note** however that the code line where you are using the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_split.htm) method is not completed properly.... If you read the linked tutorial you will find that this method is used to fill a [String Array](https://www.journaldev.com/17809/java-string-array) which is good because ***usually***, this is what you want to do with file data lines. Doing so of course allows you to retrieve the exact data portion desired from each data file line.

No one here has a clue what is contained within your specific data text file because like so many others the contents within it is obviously so supper-duper classified that not even fictitious data will suffice. Because of this there is in no way a means provide you with an accurate **array index value** or **values** to use against your **String Array** in order to retrieve your desired data from each data file line. This is good however since it is you who needs to figure this out and once you do you will have the task beaten to submission.